# How to surpass rate limiting in Twitter?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to extract data from Twitter. The data includes the tweets and people who retweeted a particular tweet. I have 46,000 tweets and I need to find retweeters for each of the tweet. Further, using Twitter call: retweet/id, you can pass only one id at a time, limiting 15 requests per 15 minutes.
Is there any way to surpass this limit and make unlimited calls?

Comment: No, it's not possible in REST api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not through the REST API, no.

You may want to investigate Twitter's [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/streaming) to see if the functionality it provides meets your needs.  Accessing it is a little more complex than the REST API, but it may be able to help you meet your needs.

You will find people who will tell you to do things like set up dummy accounts and dummy applications.  Don't do this.  Twitter actively monitors the API for use patterns like this and you will find your applications and IP addresses blacklisted.

Comment: Thanks. I wont do the dummy stuff. So I was thinking of other way around i.e. fetch all the tweets and then see if there is retweet id embedded in them. Do you think I can get the retweeters without making an explicit call for it, rather stream the tweets and find it in json tweets? Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't done much with the Streaming API, but I can tell you that the task of processing 46,000 tweets is not the sort of thing that the REST API is designed for.  I feel pretty confident in saying that there's no reasonable to way do this through the REST API.  May I ask what sort of task requires you to examine 46,000 tweets?

Comment: I want to find the users which are highly engaged with a celebrity twitter account. So I will extract all tweets and see the unique users who are retweeting, are mentioned or favouriting those tweets. Thereby I will score them and find the engagement.

Comment: In that case, your best bet is probably to use the streaming API so you can catch these tweets in real-time and store the information in a local database of your own creation.  The rate limits will not allow you to get the amount of data you want.

Comment: Yeah but the streaming tweets just give the count of retweet and not the people who retweeted. So thats the problem. :(

Comment: If a tweet is a retweet, it should have the retweet-of-id as part of its properties.  If that is on the tweets coming out of the streaming API, and you have a list of tweets you are tracking, couldn't you accomplish it in that way?

Comment: Yes, that is true. It might be a little complex and exhaustive but solves the purpose. Thanks buddy